# Remove space between selected images in a column

Tags: css, html, alignment, image

I have a series of images split up by spacer divs, but I need the images to be one after another without any spacing. I have tried

```
float:left
```

which gives the effect I want, but throws everything to the left, and removes all padding.

```
display: block
```

doesn't seem to affect my images.

but neither have given the desired

```
<div class="stage">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
            <img src="images/portfolio/GifHeader32col.gif" >
            <img src="images/portfolio/lights.png" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/SG-Body.png" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/footer.png" >
    <div class="spacer"></div>
            <img src="images/portfolio/GifHeader32col.gif" >
            <img src="images/portfolio/lights.png" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/SLT-Body.png" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/footer.png" >
    <div class="spacer"></div>
            <img src="images/portfolio/GifHeader32col.gif" >
            <img src="images/portfolio/lights.png" />
            <img src="images/portfolio/SSG-Body.png"/>
            <img src="images/portfolio/footer.png" >
    <div class="spacer"</div>
</div>
```

I have tried everything I can think of, but my css/html is still very primitive.
Thanks a lot.

Edit: CSS

```
#stage {
width: 700px;
}
```

-

```
.spacer {
height: 1px;
clear: both;
border-bottom: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #d6d6d6;
margin: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use an element specifically for breaking up the page, use `hr` (horizontal rule), not `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this in your CSS:**

```
.stage img{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 24px 0px;
}
```

**NOTE:** double check your *(last div class="spacer")* it must be:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

--->hope it helps..™

Comment: Although this is not what I used, I totally forgot i could use padding to re-align it.

in the end i used

    div.image-container img {
 display:inline;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 50px;
    }

Which was a combination of all your efforts.

once again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Images are inline, so to remove spacing you will need to literally do so.

i.e.

```
        <img src="images/portfolio/GifHeader32col.gif" ><!--
     --><img src="images/portfolio/lights.png" /><!--
     --><img src="images/portfolio/SG-Body.png" /><!--
     --><img src="images/portfolio/footer.png" >
```

Alternatively you could put them in an unordered list and float the list elements to the left.

Answer (score 0):

if you put every image in a line, all the images will have spaces among them.

if you wanna keep the images in one line, put the images inside a `<div class="image-container">` and put a `float: "left"` property on `.image-container img`.

Comment: Whilst this does remove the spacing, it un-centers them. Is there anyway to keep them centralized?

Comment: i don't know how your structure is, so i can't answer this accurately, but you could set a width to this div and put `margin: 0 auto`, so it will have both left and right margins equal, what means centered

Comment: also, using a spacer to keep them centered is not exactly a good practice, cause it might not be centered if the user has a different screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? 
http://jsfiddle.net/5QJhg/

```
.stage img { float: left; }
.spacer { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect, but it throws all the images to the left, which does remove the spacing, but doesnt align with the rest of my page.